# sql query to get the time period the position was tagged to the employee

Tags: sql, oracle

The table below gives assignment and position details

| ASG_NUMBER | START_dATE | END_DATE | JOB_CODE | GRADE_CODE | POS_CDOE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 01-JAN-2021 | 08-JUN-2021 | S29 | Engineer | Manager |
| 10 | 09-JUL-2021 | 31-DEC-2021 | S29 | Sr. Engineer | Manager |
| 10 | 01-JAN-2022 | 31-DEC-4712 | S56 | principal | Sr.Manager |
| 11 | 16-FEB-2021 | 22-NOV-2021 | A1 | Marketing | Analyst |
| 11 | 23-NOV-2021 | 31-DEC-4712 | A2 | Marketing | Analyst |
| 14 | 09-Feb-2020 | 18-JUL-2021 | G1 | Principal | Manager |
| 14 | 19-JUL-2021 | 22-SEP-2021 | G2 | Sr.Principal | Manager |
| 14 | 23-sep-2021 | 31-dec-4712 | G3 | Sr.Principal | Manager |

I want the Time in current_Position & Time in Previous Position values which show the time period in years and months the employee was in the current or previous positions

| asg_number | Time in current_Position | Time in Previous Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 m | 6 m |
| 11 | 1y 4 m | 1 y 4 m |
| 14 | 2y 4m | 2y 4m |

when there is no position change then both these columns should be the same. Which function to use

Comment: Please describe exact issue you have: find time difference? find previous value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` and `MONTHS_BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT asg_number,
       CASE
       WHEN time_in_post >= 12
       THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(time_in_post/12), 'fm90') || 'y '
       END
       ||
       CASE
       WHEN TRUNC(MOD(time_in_post,12)) > 0
       THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(time_in_post,12)), 'fm90') || 'm'
       END AS time_in_post,
       CASE
       WHEN prev_time_in_post >= 12
       THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(prev_time_in_post/12), 'fm90') || 'y '
       END
       ||
       CASE
       WHEN TRUNC(MOD(prev_time_in_post,12)) > 0
       THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(prev_time_in_post,12)), 'fm90') || 'm'
       END AS prev_time_in_post
FROM   (
  SELECT asg_number,
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(LEAST(SYSDATE, curr_end_date), curr_start_date)
           AS time_in_post,
         CASE NUM_SAME_POS
         WHEN 1
         THEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(prev_end_date, prev_start_date)
         ELSE MONTHS_BETWEEN(LEAST(SYSDATE, curr_end_date), curr_start_date)
         END AS prev_time_in_post
  FROM   table_name
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY asg_number
    ORDER     BY end_date DESC
    MEASURES
      FIRST(same_pos_code.end_date)  AS curr_end_date,
      LAST(same_pos_code.start_date) AS curr_start_date,
      COUNT(same_pos_code.end_date)  AS num_same_pos,
      FIRST(diff_pos_code.end_date)  AS prev_end_date,
      LAST(diff_pos_code.start_date) AS prev_start_date
    PATTERN ( ^ same_pos_code+ diff_pos_code* )
    DEFINE
      same_pos_code AS FIRST(same_pos_code.pos_code) = pos_code,
      diff_pos_code AS FIRST(diff_pos_code.pos_code) = pos_code
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ASG_NUMBER, START_dATE, END_DATE, JOB_CODE, GRADE_CODE, POS_CODE) AS
SELECT 10, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-06-08', 'S29', 'Engineer',     'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2021-07-09', DATE '2021-12-31', 'S29', 'Sr. Engineer', 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '4712-12-31', 'S56', 'principal',    'Sr.Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-02-16', DATE '2021-11-22', 'A1',  'Marketing',    'Analyst' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-11-23', DATE '4712-12-31', 'A2',  'Marketing',    'Analyst' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, DATE '2020-02-09', DATE '2021-07-18', 'G1',  'Principal',    'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, DATE '2021-07-19', DATE '2021-09-22', 'G2',  'Sr.Principal', 'Manager' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, DATE '2021-09-23', DATE '4712-12-31', 'G3',  'Sr.Principal', 'Manager' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ASG_NUMBER | TIME_IN_POST | PREV_TIME_IN_POST |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10 | 6m | 11m |
> | 11 | 1y 4m | 1y 4m |
> | 14 | 2y 4m | 2y 4m |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bbe4326cbde95820ded306dee6efce78)*

Comment: @MTO im a curious novice and was wondering if this Could this be done with lead or lag? I have this code for date difference. select start_date, end_date    ,trunc(months_between(end_date, start_date) / 12) as yrs         ,trunc(mod(months_between(end_date, start_date), 12)) as mnths
         ,trunc(end_date - add_months(start_date, trunc(months_between(end_date, start_date)))) as dys
  from table_name;

Comment: @Pugzly It can be done, but nowhere near as easily as with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=18f2a2df4ebc328e667c5aa34367af2c)

Comment: @MT0 - This is really awesome ! I did not know about this function. Thank you !